# Customize Access Denied Warning

Tags: laravel

how can I correctly redirect this access ban if you don't have the correct role? The notice is very bare, showing errors, I would like it to redirect to the home with a notice.

```
namespace jeremykenedy\LaravelRoles\App\Exceptions;

class RoleDeniedException extends AccessDeniedException
{
    /**
     * Create a new role denied exception instance.
     *
     * @param string $role
     */
    public function __construct($role)
    {
        $this->message = sprintf("You don't have a required ['%s'] role.", $role);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `render` function of the `RoleDeniedException` class.

```
    /**
     * Render the exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request)
    {
        return redirect('home');
    }
```

For more details, see below links;

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirects

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-redirect